# Symfony doesn't dispatch security.authentication.failure event for HTTP Digest

Tags: symfony, events, authentication, http-digest

I'm trying to implement login failure listener for HTTP Digest authentication with Symfony 2.6.6 and it's standard Security component. I've created a service with following configuration:

```
sp_security.auth_listener:
    class: SP\SecurityBundle\Security\AuthListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.failure, method: onAuthenticationFailure }
```

It works perfectly for HTTP Basic and traditional form login, but doesn't work for HTTP Digest.

It seems that Symfony's `DigestAuthenticationListener` never dispatches `security.authentication.failure` event.

Is it bug or normal workflow?